# Where can I find the number of family caregivers in the United States by year?

Tags: data-request, usa, medical

There are data sources like [Caregiver Action](https://www.caregiveraction.org/resources/caregiver-statistics) that cite the AARP with data every 4 - 5 years, for example, and there are past supplements to surveys like the [CDC's BRFSS](https://www.cdc.gov/aging/caregiving/caregiver-brief.html), but I'm looking for a data source that has relatively recent data, **by year**, on something like "X# of people ages 18 - 45 care for an elderly family member or a child or a sick family member."